# R ggplot2: legend should be discrete and not continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following data:

```
benchmark   mispredpenal    IPC     pred
ammp        1               1.0589  2lev
ammp        5               1.0450  2lev
...
```

and use the following command:

```
ggplot(IPC, aes(x = benchmark, y = IPC, group=mispredpenal, colour=mispredpenal)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Everything looks like it should, but I would like the legend to be discrete, and not the continuous (gradient). How should I do this?

**Edit:**
Misprediction is either 1, 5, 9, 13 or 17.

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want the variable `mispredpenal` to be a `factor` in that case:

```r
ggplot(IPC, aes(x = benchmark, y = IPC, group=factor(mispredpenal), colour=factor(mispredpenal))) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

Comment: Almost did the job, had to use colour=factor(mispredpenal) instead. Thanks!